# Автоформирование формы ввода по json?

Tags: javascript, json

Есть ли библиотеки для автоформирования более менее привлекательных форм по json формату?
То есть парсится прототип json файла и формируются формы с input и.т.д. Которые можно уже быстро связать с базой или хранилищем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну да есть интересные генераторы, из которых можно взять логику, или использовать их самих.

Небольшой список:

1. [schemaform.io](http://schemaform.io/examples/bootstrap-example.html)
2. [json-forms](https://github.com/brutusin/json-forms)
3. [json-form (jQuery plugin)](https://github.com/joshfire/jsonform)

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, что для вас "привлекательные формы", но для генерации есть вот такая библиотека: http://www.alpacajs.org/demos/form-builder/form-builder.html

```
$('#div').alpaca({
    "schema": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "email": {
                "type": "string",
                "required": false
            },
            "password": {
                "type": "string",
                "required": false,
                "pattern": {}
            },
            "file": {
                "type": "string",
                "required": false
            },
            "check": {
                "type": "boolean",
                "required": false,
                "default": true
            }
        }
    },
    "options": {
        "fields": {
            "email": {
                "type": "text",
                "label": "Email Address"
            },
            "password": {
                "type": "password",
                "label": "Password"
            },
            "file": {
                "type": "file",
                "label": "File Upload"
            },
            "check": {
                "type": "checkbox",
                "rightLabel": "Sign me up for the News Letter!",
                "label": "Newsletter"
            }
        },
        "focus": false
    },
    "data": {
        "email": "Joe Smith",
        "password": "MyPassword"
    }
});
```